# Number theory: Proof: Prove that $3 \in QR_p \iff p \equiv \pm1 \pmod{12}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove $3 \in QR_p \iff p \equiv \pm1 \pmod{12}$.

I'm not too sure where to go with this one. I was trying to use the fact that, for the case of $3$, $3 \in QR_p \iff p \in QR_3$...

Thanks!

Comment: The edited version is not correct either. Did you read what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good. But the equivalence is not quite correct. Recall that there is a factor $(-1)^{(p-1)(q-1)/4}$ in the quadratic reciprocity formula. If $q=3$ this simlifies to $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$. Yet this still does depend of $p$ modulo $4$, which explains why the result is modulo $12$, as it is  $3 \times 4$.

Comment: "This still does not depend on $p \pmod 4$"? Sorry, I'm a little lost. Where did the $\pmod 4$ come from?

Comment: It does depend on $p$ mod $4$. Whether $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$ is $1$ or $-1$ depends on whether $(p-1)/2$ is odd /even which depends on it is $3$ or $1$ mod $4$.

Comment: Right. That makes sense. Thanks! Upcoming test - I swear stress makes people stupider.

Answer (score 0):

$$3‎\in QR(P)‎\Longleftrightarrow x^2‎\equiv 3 \bmod p ‎\Longleftrightarrow(x^2)^{(p-1)/2}‎\equiv 3^{(p-1)/2} \bmod p ‎‎$$
 $$‎\Rightarrow3^{(p-1)/2}‎\equiv x^{p-1}‎\equiv 1 \bmod p ‎\Longleftrightarrow 3^{(p-1)/2}‎\equiv 1 \bmod p ‎\Longleftrightarrow {(p -1)/2}=6 k‎
‎\Longleftrightarrow p ‎\equiv  \pm 1 \bmod 12$$

Comment: Can you explain your step $3^{(p-1)/2}=1 \pmod p \iff (p-1)/2 = 6k$?

Comment: well.$$3^{(p-1)/2}=1modp\Longleftrightarrow‎3^{(p-1)}=1modp\Longleftrightarrow‎(p,3)=1‎‎‎\Longrightarrow‎...$$

Comment: I suggest using at least some words in an answer; it would make it easier to follow your logic. Also, consider using `\bmod` command: $1\bmod p$ is `1\bmod p`, for example.

Comment: I do not understand the comment. $3^{p-1}$ is $1$ mod $p$ for every prime $p$ but $3$. How can any condition arise from this?